# How to centre and bold a heading in RMarkdown and LaTeX?

Tags: r, markdown

I am a new LaTeX and RMarkdown user. I am currently compiling reports using RMarkdown (in RStudio) but am unsure how to centre and bold one of my headings? For example, my document looks like this:

````
---
title: <center> <h1>Call Centre Report</h1> </center>
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Arial
fig_crop: false
toc: true
classoption: landscape
fontsize: 14pt
geometry: margin=0.5in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---
<style>
  .main-container {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
  }
</style>

```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```
\newpage

# Iris 

```{r fig.width=18, fig.height=7, echo=FALSE, comment=" "}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme_classic()
```
````

I wish to have the "Iris" heading centred and bold while retaining it's format as a heading to appear in the TOC, but am unsure how to do so?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A package that doesn't clash wit the [pandoc default.latex template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex#L142) is [`sectsty`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty)

At the end of the yaml, direct under `header-includes` add the package

```
...
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering \emph}
---
```

See the package manual for more option